# FTP to Drupal sites/default/files permission error

Tags: drupal, permissions, ftp, drupal-7

I would like to upload files via FTP to the sites/default/sites directory in Drupal 7, but I am receiving a 550 access denied error. I also can't CHMOD it because I get a 550: Operation not permitted. I have googled this but, can't seem to find an answer. This is on a shared host so I do not have access to terminal. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the files created by drupal in the sites/default/files directory are using the *apache* user. So by ftp if you are not a root user, you will not be able to change anything and apache  user doesn't have login access, so no change even there. Only way to achieve this seems to be using either root user. Also consider using some file browser modules or IMCE or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. I am now using ElFinder which allows me to batch download and upload files with drupal 7.